# Qt WebKit and HTML5 geolocation

Tags: javascript, html, qt, geolocation

I’m learning HTML5 and testing the new features on a Qt hybrid application.
Now I’m working on a simple geolocation example but when I call navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocation); it seems the QtWebKit does not support it, but acording to this http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/QtWebKitFeatures22 the version of QtWebKit that comes with Qt4.8.0 supports geolocation.

This is the code I’m using:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    getMyLocation();      
}

function getMyLocation()
{
    if(navigator.geolocation)
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocation);        
    }  
    else
    {
        alert("No geolocation support");  
    }
}

function displayLocation(position)
{
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    var div = document.getElementById("location");

    div.innerHTML = "You are at Latitude: " + latitude + ", Longitude: " + longitude;  
}
```

And on the Qt side:

```
QWebView* MyWindow::createWebView()
    {
        QWebSettings* default_settings = QWebSettings::globalSettings();
        default_settings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptEnabled,true);
        default_settings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::OfflineStorageDatabaseEnabled,true);
        default_settings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::OfflineWebApplicationCacheEnabled,true);
        default_settings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls,true);        
        default_settings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::LocalStorageEnabled,true);
        default_settings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptCanAccessClipboard,true);
        default_settings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::DeveloperExtrasEnabled,true);

        QWebView* web_view = new QWebView(this);

        connect(web_view->page()->mainFrame(), SIGNAL(javaScriptWindowObjectCleared()),
                this, SLOT(addJavascriptObject()));

        inspector_->setPage(web_view->page());

        inspector_->setVisible(true);
        inspector_->show();

        web_view->load(QUrl("qrc:/html/geolocation_example.html"));

        return web_view;
    }
```

Anyone knows how to enable Html5 geolocation for a Qt desktop app?

Answer (score 2):

You need to subclass `QWebPage` and make a signal handler for the `QWebPage::featurePermissionRequested(QWebFrame*, QWebPage::Feature)` signal.

Here is a reference implementation:

```
class WebPage : public QWebPage
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        WebPage(QObject* parent = 0) :
            QWebPage(parent)
        {
            connect(this, SIGNAL(featurePermissionRequested(QWebFrame*, QWebPage::Feature)), SLOT(permissionRequested(QWebFrame*, QWebPage::Feature)));
        }

        virtual ~WebPage()
        {
        }

    private slots:
        void permissionRequested(QWebFrame* frame, QWebPage::Feature feature)
        {
            setFeaturePermission(frame, feature, PermissionGrantedByUser);
        }
};
```

Use `QWebView::setPage()` with an instance of your newly created subclass to make QtWebKit use your `QWebPage` implementation.

In case you need more help, have a look at the `QtMiniBrowser` which is part of the WebKit.org repository. The source code is available from here http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Tools/QtTestBrowser

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't even get to call navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocation); It can't find navigator.geolocation

Comment: userX731, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I tried implementing this using PyQt4, but the featurePermissionRequested signal never seems to fire.