# How to use QtWebkit with geolocation?

Tags: c++, qt, geolocation, qtwebkit, qwebview

It is possible to use geolocation in *Desktop applications* with `QWebView`?

> - I tried [Qt WebKit and HTML5 geolocation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9865290/1518921), but not work.
> - I tried [it's the qt5 position api support for desktop app(like mac or windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27359547/1518921), but the answer is on the QT APIs, I believe it is possible to customize the "event" in some way, as is done using `qwebkitplatformplugin` to customize some features of `qtwebkit` (MultipleSelections, Notifications, Haptics, TouchInteraction, FullScreenVideoPlayer and SpellChecker).

I tried set `PermissionGrantedByUser`, but not work:

```
void WebPage::permissionRequested(QWebFrame* frame, Feature feature)
{
    switch (feature) {
        case Geolocation:
            qDebug() << "GEO-Location: PermissionGrantedByUser";
            setFeaturePermission(frame, feature, PermissionGrantedByUser);
        break;
        default:
            qDebug() << "";
    }
}
```

- I tried add this `QT += positioning`, but not work
- I tried add this `TARGET.CAPABILITY += NetworkServices Location`, but not work, I believe this is for smartphones, like Symbian.

Event `displayLocation` and `watchPosition` are never fired and using `{timeout: ...}` it shows the message `Timeout expired`:

```
<script>
function displayError(err) {
    document.getElementById("geo").innerHTML = ("Error Code: " + err.code +
        " / msg: " + err.message);
}

function displayLocation(position) {
    document.getElementById("geo").innerHTML = [
        "latitude:" + position.coords.latitude,
        "longitude:" + position.coords.longitude
    ].join(", ");
}

function getMyLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(a, b, c) {
            console.log(a, b, c);
            document.getElementById("geo").innerHTML = "Testando...";
        });
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocation, displayError, {
            enableHighAccuracy: false,
            timeout: 10000,
            maximumAge: 0
        });
    } else {
        document.getElementById("geo").innerHTML = "No geolocation support";
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    getMyLocation();
};
</script>
<div id="geo"></div>
```

I believe that I have to build a library and put in the `qtDir/compiler/plugins/position` folder, but do not know where to start.

How can I do this?

Or is it possible to customize the event and send coordinates of a *3rdparty lib* (I'm not asking for a library and I'm not asking for alternatives in javascript) in response to the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`?

---

### Extra info about

If use `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1` in debug mode *Application Output* return this (note that the first line is generated by `WebPage::permissionRequested`):

```
GEO-Location: PermissionGrantedByUser
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "C:/Qt5.4.0/5.4/mingw491_32/plugins/position" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "C:/Qt5.4.0/5.4/mingw491_32/plugins/position/qtposition_positionpoll.dll"
Found metadata in lib C:/Qt5.4.0/5.4/mingw491_32/plugins/position/qtposition_positionpoll.dll, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.qt.position.sourcefactory/5.0",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "positionpoll"
        ],
        "Monitor": true,
        "Position": false,
        "Priority": 1000,
        "Provider": "positionpoll",
        "Satellite": false
    },
    "className": "QGeoPositionInfoSourceFactoryPoll",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 328704
}


"The plugin 'C:/Qt5.4.0/5.4/mingw491_32/plugins/position/qtposition_positionpoll.dll' uses incompatible Qt library. (Cannot mix debug and release libraries.)"
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "C:/Qt5.4.0/5.4/mingw491_32/plugins/position/qtposition_positionpolld.dll"
Found metadata in lib C:/Qt5.4.0/5.4/mingw491_32/plugins/position/qtposition_positionpolld.dll, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.qt.position.sourcefactory/5.0",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "positionpoll"
        ],
        "Monitor": true,
        "Position": false,
        "Priority": 1000,
        "Provider": "positionpoll",
        "Satellite": false
    },
    "className": "QGeoPositionInfoSourceFactoryPoll",
    "debug": true,
    "version": 328704
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("positionpoll")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "C:/projects/webview-example/debug/position" ...
```

Comment: did u build qt on your own? If yes, can u add `-DENABLE_GEOLOCATION=1` during build ? This since there is check for preprocessor `ENABLE_GEOLOCATION` in qt source repo.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using the installer (binary version) of QT, I try to download the "src" and build with `ENABLE_GEOLOCATION`.

Comment: please ignore the earlier suggestion if you are already using installer. If using installer, I think flag is already enabled. May be, you can confirm by search in header files.

Comment: @Kiran headers files from `qtDir/compiler/include`? **Note:** I used `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1`, this returned a few details, see my last edition. Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/qtproject/qtwebkit/blob/24a674183c7b620b8a12734f8a4da3a601939238/Source/WebCore/Modules/geolocation/NavigatorGeolocation.h    warning: *i might be driving you in wrong direction. there could be a simple way*